# How to generate the TPC-DS benchmarking data 1 TB in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, benchmarking, tpc

I want to generate the TPC-DS data (1 TB and 10 TB) directly in AWS S3 without transferring from local machine to s3. What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I did similar work several month ago, [hive-testbench](https://github.com/hortonworks/hive-testbench) can be an option. 
Check the `README.md` about how to make it happen.

You need to configure `fs.defaultFS` in `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml` to your AWS S3 bucket, the data will be generated in AWS directly.
Pass data scale parameter to `./tpcds-setup.sh` to generate date with different scale.